# How to make sure currently selected text gets deleted when typing new text?

Tags: text-editing, region, delete-selection-mode

When editing text, editors' usual behaviour is to replace selected text with the next text.  In Emacs, when text is selected and you enter new characters, the new text gets inserted at point, leaving the current selection intact.

How to get Emacs to delete selected text when typing new characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add this line in your init file:

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)
```